# How to reach best performence with different data types?

Tags: c++, types, casting

I am working on custom class, which holds Date and Time. The main goal of that class is reaching the best performance. My target platform is Linux
Currently, I hold members like this

```
Year - int
Month - int
Day - int
Hour- int
Min - int
Sec - double (because I need milisecs as well).
```

What I am thinking now is too change types to following

```
   Year - unsigned short
    Month - unsigned char
    Day - unsigned char
    Hour- unsigned char
    Min - unsigned char
    Sec - unsigned char
    Milisec - unsigned short
```

Which gives me 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 2 = 9 bytes.
As you already guessed I want to fit my class into 8 byte(there are no other members).
So what is the best approach to solve it, to merge(e. g. seconds and miliseconds) and use bit masks for retrieving values? Will it affect performance? And what if user passes integers to some setter, would type cast affect performance also ?

Thanks on advance.

Comment: why do you want to fit your class into 8 bytes?

Comment: If you only need year 1900 to 2155 use a `unsigned char`.

Comment: Due to the inherent problems with using floating point arithmetic, storing the milliseconds as a separate integer field is probably a good idea.

Comment: You'll never need more than four digits to store the year...

Comment: But why limit yourself to only 8 bytes? Such limitations are usually only used on extreme platforms where you count the memory in kilobytes, not megabytes (like Linux requires).

Comment: Also, having the structure packed to avoid padding, some members will be on unaligned addresses which might affect the performance negative (though not going to be noticeable on any CPU running at least a couple of hundred MHz).

Comment: What makes you think that best performance = smaller class size? Are you pre-emptively optimizing or thit you already assess that size (copying data) really is slowing your application down?

Comment: Why not use time_t (signed integer) + milliseconds and split later?

Comment: Are you familiar with Donald Knuth ? [I'm just asking....](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Comment: And if you *really* want to save space, you can get lower than that by using bit-fields.

Comment: Space is not a so important for me, I've just thought that storing class into 8 Bytes will increase performance. cause CPU can handle it in one tact.

Comment: @KerrekSB: ... I finally have a secure job when I'll be required to fix the year 10'000 bug! :-))    (my real name is "MacLeod")

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options you have here. The most compact way would be to have an integer timestamp. It would take a bit of processing to unpack it though. Another option is to use C++ bitfields to pack things tighter. For example, month only needs 4 bits, day 5 bits, minutes and seconds 6 bits. It should make things a bit slower, but only in theory. It all depends on the number of these dates you have and on the amount and kind of processing you're going to perform on them. In some cases having the `struct` tightly packed into bitfields would increase the performance because of higher memory throughput and better cache utilization. In other cases, the bit manipulation might become more expensive. Like always with performance, better not to guess, but **measure**.

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way here is to put pair of sec and millisec into one int (two bytes).
You don't need separate Sec (unsigned char) and Milisec (unsigned short), because you can put number from 0 to 60000 into one unsigned short.

Let's call it milliSecPack (unsigned short).

```
milliSecPack = 60 * Sec + Milisec;
```

And

```
Sec = milliSecPack / 1000;
Milisec = milliSecPack % 1000;
```